# SQL OR statement without having to repeat

Tags: sql

Is it possible to have an `OR` statement in an SQL query without having to repeat information that doesn't change? Take this as an example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE a = 1
AND b = 1
AND c = 1
AND x = 1
AND y = 2
OR a = 1
AND b = 1
AND c = 1
AND x = 2
AND y = 1
```

This is the only way I can figure out how to do it. a,b and c do not change so I see it as illogical to have to repeat them when they stay the same. Is there any way to avoid having to repeat values that don't change when including an `OR` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WHERE  a = 1
AND    b = 1
AND    c = 1
AND    (
         ( x = 1 AND y = 2 )
       OR
         ( x = 2 AND y = 1 )
       )
```

Alternative option (which is clearer IMO):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
        SELECT *
        FROM   table
        WHERE  a = 1
        AND    b = 1
        AND    c = 1
       ) As a_subquery
WHERE  (x = 1 AND y = 2)
    OR (x = 2 AND y = 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE a = 1 AND b = 1 AND c = 1
AND 
( 
   (x = 1 AND y = 2) OR (x = 2 AND y = 1)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use parentheses:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE a = 1
AND b = 1
AND c = 1
AND (x = 1 AND y=2
     OR x=2 AND y = 1)
```